# Datepicker. firstDay: 1 option not working

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I'm trying to make my calendar starting from Monday.
Here is my code:

```
        var datepicker_min = __webpack_require__(448);
        var date = new Date;
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
        if (document.querySelector("[data-datepicker]")) {
            const picker = datepicker_min("[data-datepicker]", {
                startDay: '+1d',
                minDate: date,
                firstDay: 1,
                formatter: (input, date, instance) => {
                    const value = date.toLocaleDateString();
                    let value1 = value.split("/");
                    let temp1 = value1[0];
                    value1[0] = value1[1];
                    value1[1] = temp1;
                    input.value = value1.join("");
                },
                onSelect: function(input, instance, date) {}
            });
            flsModules.datepicker = picker;
        }
```

Option firstDay: 1 - not working

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Which datepicker? Please add relevant CDN to the snippet I asked you to make